# Access to a restricted PHP script from another PHP script

Tags: php

I have scripts named `MathTest.php` and `PhysicsTest.php`. Using `.htaccess` I have made sure that they cannot be invoked directly by users. Now I have another script `SelectTest.php` which contains two submits: one for accessing `MathTest.php` and another for accessing `PhysicsTest.php`. I use `header('Location: MathTest.php')` and `header('Location: PhysicsTest.php')` to run the scripts. How can I allow `SelectTest.php` to run `MathTest.php` and `PhysicsTest.php`?

Answer (score -1):

Get the form button to reload SelectTest.php and then use an "if" statement to "include" the MathTest or PhysicsTest PHP files into the SelectTest file itself.

There's no need to use "Location" headers to redirect etc as you can just include the appropriate PHP file in to SelectTest, which is already publicly accessible

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Something along the lines of

```
<?php
// This is your SelectTest.php file

if ($_GET['test'] == 'maths')
{
    include 'MathsTest.php';
}
elseif ($_GET['test'] == 'physics')
{
    include 'PhysicsTest.php';
}
else
{
    die('No test found');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Benr77.But the  problem is that `SelectTest.php` has its own `session_start()` and session variables and `mathTest.php` has its own. I mean I don't want them to get messed up.

Comment: That's not a problem. Just isolate the session vars in arrays - e.g.

`$_SESSION['maths']['someMathsSessionVar'] = 'foo';`